# Combining inequalities

Tags: inequality

When working through the division algorithm I came across a combined inquality that does not strike me as obvious.  This fact is used to prove the uniqueness of the remainder.

Given that $0 \leq r < b$ and $0 \leq r_1 < b$, we have

$$-b < r - r_1 < b.$$

Is there a obvious way to combine these guys?  Is there some bounded theorem I an use here?  I can see that the result is true, I just do not see a comcrete way of getting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\leqslant r\lt b$ and $-b_1\lt -r_1\leqslant -a_1$ then $a-b_1\lt r-r_1\lt b-a_1$.

Comment: It is much more clear if you put it that way.  It helps, thank you very much.